# How to refresh Google Service account which expires after 1 hour?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am using Google Drive API(C#) with service account as mentioned in

https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

I am able to work with DriveService object, but after 1 hr, it errors out with exception: "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

I know, by setting "access_type" to "offline" we could solve this problem, but I am not able to set this property for DriveService object.
Does anyone know how to refresh this Google Drive Service object?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set offline access mode, your app gets a refresh token when the user logs in for the first time.

> access_type :: 
>   Indicates if your application needs to access a Google API when the
>   user is not present at the browser. This parameter defaults to online.
>   If your application needs to refresh access tokens when the user is
>   not present at the browser, then use offline. This will result in your
>   application obtaining a refresh token the first time your application
>   exchanges an authorization code for a user.

You later use this refresh token to obtain a new access token, once the current access token expires. Basically, your app would then hit the token exchange endpoint (POST to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token) with the refresh token and your client credentials - google with then issue a (refresh token + access token) pair to you.
See [this link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline) for further clarification.

**EDIT** - 
I checked the Service Account documentation and found a sample C# app that fetches and uses refresh tokens too. See it [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet).
I hope this one helps.

Comment: Thanks Divyanshm....But I am not using Google OAuth2.0 authentication..I am using Google Service account authentication for domain users....I've found something like this.....             provider.RefreshToken(auth.State);.............this will refresh DriveService object....But is there any automatic refresh thing in Service account authentication...like access_type=offline?

Comment: Added some more info that I could find. I hope this helps you.

Comment: page not found :\

Answer (score 3):

Service accounts come with a private key - and that's their moral equivalent/superset of the refresh token that is returned as a result of a user-driven consent flow.

When a user consents to offline access (via a web server or similar OAuth flow) a refresh token is returned that can be swapped (along with the client secret) at any time for an access token.

In the same manner a service account private key can be used to sign an assertion that can also be swapped for an access token - that's useful for cases where no user is present to accept a consent screen, or where you are performing work on behalf of other users in your organization.

Once you get an access token it is treated in the same way - and is expected to expire after 1 hour, at which time a new access token will need to be requested, which for a service account means creating and signing a new assertion.

Generally noticing that the access token is expired and requesting a new one is taken care of for you by the Google client libraries - although I'm not familiar with the C# version. If you could share your code that creates the DriveService object that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks aeijdenberg....I am using the code placed @https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation#instantiate_a_drive_service_object...Here we need to refresh authentication object.. I am using provider.RefreshToken(((OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>)OAuthenticator).State);....before it expires and it is working for me.  Thanks again